# How do you convert input "add 1 2" to "1+2"

Tags: java, string, variables

If the prompt is allowing user to input "add 1 2"

How do you convert this into 1+2 and output the answer?

Same for "sub 1 2"
to 1-2

I do know that it is possible to split into arrays to solve this problem, but my teacher won't let us do so for this assignment, all we allowed is using if while and for loop.

I have my idea of codes as following, but it just won't let me go through as double i = line.nextDouble() won't work

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shell {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to CS302Shell! "
            + "Enter help for a list of commands or exit to end.");

    String command = input.next();
    String line = input.nextLine();

    if (command.equals("add")) {
        double i = line.nextDouble();
    }






} /** method */
```

} /** class */

Comment: Have you had a go yet? Show us your attempt so far so we can see where you need help.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Could you describe more generally what you want to do? Are you writing a prefix to infix converter, or something more limited?

Comment: Show us your code first, but ultimately one way is to split the string or input using a delimiter (in this case space " ") and then checking that both sides are int and then performing whichever calculation on them you need. Might need to see some code and more explanation though.

Comment: google for `pocket calculator as finite state machine`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method to split your string into the right pieces:

```
public static double calculate(String input) {

        // Here you splitt the input-String at every space. So you get 3 pieces
        String[] splitted = input.trim().replace(" +", " ").split(" ");

        // Set the different element-values to variables
        String operator = splitted[0];
        // Here you have to cast the String to double because you can't
        // calculate with a String
        double first;
        double second;

        //With this try-catch block you check if the numbers are really numbers.
        try {
            first = Double.valueOf(splitted[1]);
            second = Double.valueOf(splitted[2]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            System.err.println("Your input for one of the numbers was wrong");
            return 0;
        }
        // Now you check which operator the user wants and return the result.
        switch (operator) {
        case "add":
            return first + second;
        case "sub":
            return first - second;
        case "multiply":
            return first * second;
        case "divide":
            return first / second;

            // If de user has given a wrong input, the return is 0
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calculate("add 1 2"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

String parsing:

```
int result = 0;
String[] data = "add 1 2".split(" ");
switch(data[0]) {
    case "add":
        int param1 = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        int param2 = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
        result = param1 + param2;
        break;
    case "sub":
        //...
        break;
}
```

You get the idea.
Some data validation would be a good idea. 
Also some try/catch blocks around the parseInt calls to make sure the program doesn't blow up when someone types "add a b" etc...

Comment: Well, apparently my teacher won't let us use split for this assignment. We can only use if while for loops and very basic variable declarations.

Comment: @PeterHong -  Well, while it's a little more time consuming it's not that much harder to parse the string yourself. Look at the API docs for String.charAt() as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

You should really post your attempt first so we can better help you but I think this may be what you want. All this code is assuming you entered in correct input.

```
public int addInput(String input){
     inputs = inputs.replace("add ", "");
     String[] inputs = input.split(" ", 2);
     return Integer.parseInt(inputs[0])+Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
}

public int subInput(String input){
     inputs = inputs.replace("sub ", "");
     String[] inputs = input.split(" ", 2);
     return Integer.parseInt(inputs[0])-Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);
}
```

Seriously though seeing your code would be nice. :)